# Creating a shared database Java DB

Tags: java, database, networking, shared

I am currently working on a **Java Desktop Application**. I currently have the database on the localhost Java DB Apache Derby server. I want to access the database from multiple PC's not necessarily on the same network. How can I make my database shared and accessible from multiple PC's ? Also what could be the possible solution of the instance when 2 users simultaneously try to update the shared database.

Comment: Are these computers in one network? Btw, you can configure `transaction locks` which makes sure you lock the table once you are updating it.

Comment: No PC's are not on the same network.

Comment: The database network server must be located on a network that is accessible from all PCs that should access the database. If there are separate networks you have to create a VPN that connects the networks or make the DB server available from the Internet (in such a case don't forget the user authentication!).

Comment: I want to make it available from the Internet. So you mean database hosting? @Robert